# C - counting sentences

Tags: c

I wrote this code, but I can't handle with ".?!" and other combination of such characters? Could someone help me? I need to count the sentences in a line.

```
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<string.h>
    #include<stdio.h>

    int main(){
         int say=0,i;
         char line[250];
         gets(line);
         int k = strlen(line);
         for(i=0; i<k; i++){
            if(line[i]=='.' || line[i]=='?' || line[i]=='!'){
                say++;
             }
         }

        printf("%d\n",say);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Do not use `gets`. Instead, use `fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin)`

Comment: And what is the problem you have with the code? For some specified input, what is the actual and expected output?

Comment: You need to define what a "sentence" is. If you consider each question mark, exclamation point or period to constitute a sentence, then this program is working correctly.

Comment: And you might also want to read about [`ispunct`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/ispunct).

Comment: **unrelated to your possible problem**: `for(i=0; i<k; i++){` -> `for(i = 0 ; line[i] != '\0 ; i++)`, is a better solution.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg `ispunct` would include characters such parentheses, so I'm not sure this is the best solution for counting sentences.

Comment: My input is a unique line with max 250 characters. Some sentences end with ??? or !!! and some combination of . ? and !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add some exceptions, you can check if the character before any of `.`, `?`, `!` punctuations is the same to any of them. If yes, don't increment.

```
if(line[i]=='.' || line[i]=='?' || line[i]=='!') {
    if (i-1 > -1 && (line[i-1]!='.' && line[i-1]!='?' && line[i-1]!='!'))
        say++;
}
```

`i-1 > -1` solves a special case where any of `.`,`?`,`!` is the first character of the line and is included in the sentence count, which shouldn't be.

Tried it and `".?!"` combination will have a result of `0`.

**Results:**

```
.?!
0

?.!
0

!.?
0

!?.
0

!.?
0

.!?
0

ho hey! hello?
2

. Really?
1

Hello world!
1
```

Comment: I suggest moving `i-1 > -1` before `(line[i-1]!='.' && line[i-1]!='?' && line[i-1]!='!')`. Otherwise , if the first character of `line` is a `.` or `?` or `!`, then your code exhibits Undefined Behavior as you access `line[-1]`.

Answer (score 1):

A way to avoid the problems is by using `strtok`:

```
const char* delim = "?!.";
char *token = strtok(line, delim);

while(token != NULL)
{
    say++;
    token = strtok(NULL, delim);
}
```

Comment: What problems do we avoid this way? Can you provide an example where OP's code would fail and this would work?

Comment: The problem is from http://e-olymp.com/en/problems/912
When I submit my above code, it is calculated 50 %.

Comment: @szczurcio , As per the link given by the OP in the above comment, `Hello world!` should output 1. OP's code outputs 2 whereas my code outputs 1. It's late. I might add more details tomorrow.

Comment: @CoolGuy For `Hello world!`, OP's code returns `1` for me.

Comment: @szczurcio , Oops. I thought that the OP (and me) checked for space. Anyway, this solution solves the OP's problem.

Answer (score 1):

After you have read the line, you need to discard multiple continuous sequences of punctuation characters. You can do this with a simple state-flag:

Iterate (loop) over the input. If you have a punctuation character, then set the state (remember to initialize it to unset at the beginning). If you have a normal (non-punctuation) character and the state flag is set, then increase the sentence-counter and clear the flag. Otherwise don't do anything special.

I'll leave the implementation as an exercise.

Comment: Thank you,I think I will get it :)